# CSS3 Inline-block divs have white at top of page

Tags: html, css

I've been reading other questions but nothing seems to fix my issue.

I'm trying to create two columns that take up 50% of the screen. I've done this but there's a gap at the top which I can't fix for some reason - what am I doing wrong?

[problem](https://i.gyazo.com/524d9756d10c1368cb7871f19a0b4be4.png)

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test column</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container"><div class="col-left">
        hello
      </div><div class="col-right">
        hello
      </div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  height: 0;
}


.col-left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  background: #1DA1F2;
  height: 100vh;
}

.col-right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Add `margin: 0` to your `html, body` rule

Comment: Thank you, I am an idiot I forgot to add this in

Answer (score 0):

That is a margin

```
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: why `height:0` ?

Comment: I didn't even notice the height, I just copied OP's CSS and added a margin.